# Where do I properly start and invalidate an NSTimer?

Tags: ios, nstimer

in xcode, when i log my NSTimer, It starts at`viewDidAppear` and stops on `viewdiddisappear` which is fine, but when I go to an exit segue, the timer resumes (which I don't want to happen because its getting doubled).how do I properly stop it so it won't get doubled when called again?

..when I put in on `viewdidload`.sure it doesn't get doubled, but it won't start again since I invalidate it `viewDidDisappear` here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (self.timeInc.isValid == NO){

        self.timeInc = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f  target:self selector:@selector(updateDetailCounter:) userInfo:([Dateformatter2() dateFromString:_DetailModal[1]]) repeats:YES];


    }
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.timeInc invalidate];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean at **when I go to an exit segue**?

Comment: it goes to this unwind command located on the root view of navigated pages -(IBAction)unwindToMain:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    
}

Comment: Always call `super` if you override `viewDidAppear:`, `viewDidDisappear:`, ... If you unwind then the controller should destroy the timer before it gets destroyed - is your controller destroyed or artificially retained? When you say 'doubled', you mean you have additional timers running?

Comment: no, i mean another one will be added once I open this view once more, then another one again and again and again..which may crash the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, in the past I had the same problem in viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   if (self.timerInc) {
    [self.timerInc invalidate];
    self.timerInc = nil;
   }
   _timerInc = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doSth) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [self.timerInc invalidate];
  self.timerInc = nil;
}
```